# certbot/dns-cloudflare for authentik

Tags: docker, cloudflare, lets-encrypt, certbot

I happen to run a domain on Cloudflare DNS that I want to use for an authentik deployment. From the corresponding documentation it seems to be rather straight forward to use certbot to get ACME/letsencrypt certificates.

I modified the example snippet in docker-compose.override.yml to the following:

```
root@debian-2gb-nbg1-1:~# cat docker-compose.override.yml 
version: "3.4"

services:
    certbot:
        image: docker.io/certbot/dns-cloudflare:latest
        volumes:
            - ./certs/:/etc/letsencrypt
        # Variables depending on DNS Plugin
        environment:
            CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN: <redacted>
        command:
            - certonly
            - --non-interactive
            - --agree-tos
            - --dns-cloudflare
            # - --dns-cloudflare-credentials cloudflare.ini
            - -m <redacted>
            - -d <redacted>
            - -v
```

certbot immediately exits after running `docker-compose up -d`

The confusing part to me is, the log files says:

`certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --dns-cloudflare-credentials cloudflare.ini`

Whereas the [documentation](https://certbot-dns-cloudflare.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for certbot-dns-cloudflare says, this is a required argument.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  server:
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:9000"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:9443"
  certbot:
        image: certbot/dns-cloudflare
        volumes:
            - ./certs/:/etc/letsencrypt
            - /srv/authentik/cloudflare.ini:/srv/authentik/cloudflare.ini
        command: certonly --non-interactive --dns-cloudflare --dns-cloudflare-credentials /srv/authentik/cloudflare.ini --agree-tos -d authentik.example.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```